# How to execute a script with argument on remote machine?

Tags: ssh, sh

I have a shell script named a.sh on machine A like below:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo hello
echo $1
echo world
```

Then I log in machine A from machine B using:

```
ssh user@machineA sh -c "/home/omc/jeff/a.sh xxx"
```

I expect the result is:

```
hello
xxx
world
```

But, actually the result is:

```
hello

world
```

You can see $1 is empty.
Can anybody tell me why?
Thank a lot!

One more thing, I have to use **"ssh user@machineA sh -c"** as prefix because other team provide it and cannot change.

Comment: You don't need to use `sh -c` on an executable script.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh yourServer "bash -s" < ./your_script.sh "foo" "bar"
```